# Is there any way to ensure that any images downloaded from social media apps automatically get saved to the Locked Folder in Google Photos?

Tags: downloading, google-photos, instagram

I was curious if there was any way to ensure that all images downloaded from social media apps like Instagram or Twitter or Reddit are automatically saved in the 'Locked Folder' in Google Photos, instead of the default "Instagram" or "Twitter" or "Reddit" folder (which is specifically for media downloaded from the respective site).

Can I make some change such that downloaded photos from Instagram and the such only save in the Locked Folder (and not the default social media app folder)?